# X-editable with laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, x-editable

Hi guys I'm migration my php app to laravel. In the formal I've been using x-editable to do inline editing. Now, I want to do the same in laravel. Before I was passing the id of the row to be edited to my `update` method in my **controller**

This is how my code looks (html):

```
<td data-id="{{$subject->id}}" data-type="text" data-name="{{$subject->name}}" class="name" data-pk="{{$subject->id}}">{{$subject->name}}</td>
```

route:

```
Route::put('/subjects/update/{id}', 'SubjectsController@update');
```

script:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
});
```

I'm concatenating the id to the url like this:

```
var id = $(this).attr('data-pk');
```

When I do that it concats `undefined` instead of the id. **How can I passed the right id**?

```
$('#subjects').editable({
     container:'body',
     selector:'td.name',
     url:'/subjects/update/'+id,
     type:'PUT',
     validate:function(value){
        if ($.trim(value) === '') {
            return "Field is required";
         }
     }
});
```

controller:

In my controller this is how I was doing it without x-editable, how can I update it to match x-editable format that users `pk` `name` and `value`

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //

    $rules = array (
        'name' => 'bail|required|max:20|min:5|unique:subjects,name,'.$id,
        'level' => 'bail|required|min:4'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make ( $request->all(), $rules );
    if ($validator->fails ()) {
        return response()->json ( array (

         'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag ()->toArray ()
        ) );
    }
    else {
        $subject = Subject::findOrFail($id);
        $subject->name = $request->name;
        $subject->level = $request->level;
        $subject->save();
        return response ()->json ( $subject );
    }

}
```

This is the error I'm now getting:

> POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/subjects/update/undefined 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Hope I'm not confusing myself here. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: any specific error?

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik Just updated my post with the error I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your route to **post** instead of **put**:

```
Route::post('/subjects/update/{id}', 'SubjectsController@update');
```

xEditable makes a POST request and not a Put request

Enjoy coding!